# Probability that an inequality is satisfied

Tags: probability

If $a,b,c$ are determined by throw of a single dice thrice, then find the probability that:

$$ \frac{a}{b} + \frac b c +\frac c a \leqslant \frac{a+b}{b+c}  +\frac{b+c}{c+a} +\frac{c+a}{a+b}$$

Comment: Simply count the possible results and those satisfying the equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I did it and I thought that I should answer my question. This can be presented in a better way so that it does not seem too intuitive.

Without loss of generality assume $a\leqslant b \leqslant c$
Also assume $ a,b,c >0$

Assume $ f(a,b,c) = \frac{a}{b} + \frac b c + \frac c a -3 $

$ f(a,b,c) = \frac a b + \frac b a -2 + \frac b c +\frac c a - \frac b a -1 $

$ f(a,b,c) = \frac {(a-b)^2} {ab} + \frac {(a-b)(b-c)}{ac}  $

Now for $k>0$

$f(a+k,b+k,c+k) \leqslant f(a,b,c) $
 ( We assumed $a\leqslant b \leqslant c$ This leads to no loss in generality as we can always decide fraction to pair up with -2)

This will be true for $f(-c,-a,-b)$ also

Using $k=a+b+c$,

$ f(a+b,b+c,c+a) \leqslant f(-c,-a,-b) = f(c,a,b) = f(a,b,c) $

Hence for positive $a,b,c$ 
$ \frac{a}{b} + \frac b c + \frac c a \geqslant \frac {a+b} {b+c} + \frac {b+c}{c+a} +\frac {b+c}{c+a} $

Hence The ineuality in question is true only for $a=b=c$

Hence, answer = $ \frac 6 {216} = \frac 1 {36}$

Answer (score 3):

$a=b=c$ is clearly a solution to the stated inequality.

Let $a=b$, then $$
  0 \leqslant  \left.\frac{a+b}{b+c} + \frac{b+c}{c+a}+\frac{c+a}{a+b} - \left(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c} + \frac{c}{a}\right)\right|_{a=b} = - \frac{(b-c)^2}{2 b c} \frac{2 b + c}{b+c}
$$ that is $b=c$ is the only solution. Hence the only other possible solutions are strictly ordered triple $a<b<c$. There 20 such possibilities, and none of them satisfy the inequality. I am sure there are neater ways to see this.

Hence
$$
  \Pr\left(\frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{c} +\frac{c}{a} \leqslant \frac{a+b}{b+c}  +\frac{b+c}{c+a} +\frac{c+a}{a+b}\right) = \Pr(a=b=c) = \frac{1}{36}
$$

Confirmation with *Mathematica*:

```
In[88]:= Probability[
 a/b + b/c + c/a <= (a + b)/(b + c) + (b + c)/(c + a) + (c + a)/(a + b), 
   {a \[Distributed] DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1, 6}], 
    b \[Distributed] DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1, 6}], 
    c \[Distributed] DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1, 6}]}]

Out[88]= 1/36
```

Comment: May be it is 1/216

Comment: Not really, $\Pr(a=b=c) = \sum_{i=1}^6 \frac{1}{6^3} = \frac{1}{6^2}$.

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: That was <= ...sorry guys...

Comment: How can I prove that no 20 of them satisfy the inequality without checking for each value separately? There has got to be a good nice way.